# Why do nodes with duplicated values for binary tree get ignored- when I build the binary tree?

Tags: python, binary-tree

I am writing code to create and print a binary tree.

Here is my code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):

        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = data

    def insert(self, data):
# Compare the new value with the parent node
        if self.data:
            if data < self.data:
                if self.left is None:
                    self.left = Node(data)
                else:
                    self.left.insert(data)
            elif data > self.data:
                if self.right is None:
                    self.right = Node(data)
                else:
                    self.right.insert(data)
        else:
            self.data = data

# Print the tree
    def PrintTree(self):
        if self.left:
            self.left.PrintTree()
        print( self.data),
        if self.right:
            self.right.PrintTree()

# Use the insert method to add nodes
root = Node(1)
root.insert(2)
root.insert(2)
root.insert(3)
root.insert(4)
root.insert(4)
root.insert(3)

root.PrintTree()
```

I know the above code is correct, but the output is not what I expected, I am getting `1,2,3,4` ; when I am expecting `output` to be `1,2,2,3,4,4,3`

I suspect it is to do with the duplication of numbers, in particular the 2 and 4. Any ideas how I can tweak the code to produce the output I expect? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to the fact that when you insert you data for a duplicated value, none of your `if` conditions evaluates to `True`, since you test for `data < self.data` and `data > self.data` but not for `data <= self.data`, `data >= self.data` or `data == self.data`.

Adopt a convention, to know whether you should put it in the right or left leaf, and your code should work fine. For instance, the code:

```python
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):

        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = data

    def insert(self, data):
# Compare the new value with the parent node
        if self.data:
            if data < self.data: # Note the <= operator
                if self.left is None:
                    self.left = Node(data)
                else:
                    self.left.insert(data)
            elif data >= self.data:
                if self.right is None:
                    self.right = Node(data)
                else:
                    self.right.insert(data)
        else:
            self.data = data

# Print the tree
    def PrintTree(self):
        if self.left:
            self.left.PrintTree()
        print( self.data),
        if self.right:
            self.right.PrintTree()

# Use the insert method to add nodes
root = Node(1)
root.insert(2)
root.insert(2)
root.insert(3)
root.insert(4)
root.insert(4)
root.insert(3)

root.PrintTree()
```

produces the output:

```sh
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
```

Note that as @sabik pointed out in the comments, it may make more sense to use the "right leaf" convention. The reason for this would be to make the sort consistent. For instance, let us assume that you use the "left leaf" convention, and that you perform the following code:

```python
root = Node(1)
root.insert(2)
root.insert(10)
root.insert(10)
```

Using the "left leaf" convention, the last `10` will be in the leftmost tree, while we may expect it to be in the rightmost tree. This would put a "dead leaf" your tree: no further node would be added using this leaf as a root.

Comment: Probably the "right subtree" option would be slightly better, as it would make the sort stable

Comment: @sabik Indeed, I haven't thought about it, nice catch!